# Proof that a set of vectors is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Let $u_1,\ldots,u_k \in \mathbb R^n$,  where $k\leq n$

Show that:

If $|u_{jj}| > \sum\limits_{i \neq j}|u_{ij}|$
(sum over the i's) then the vectors are linearly independent ( $u_{ij}$ denotes the $i$-th coordinate of the $j$-th vector).

I tried to prove by contradiction but with no success.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Thanks for fixing the formatting, I'm new with TEX.
|*| stands for the standard norm and the ij subscript refers to the i-th coordinate of the j-th vector.

Comment: I guess |x| is just the absolute value of $x$ here, not any kind of a norm.

Comment: Look at this first: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose they are linearly dependent.

Then there would exist some combination.

$a_1 u_1 + a_2 u_2 + \cdots a_k u_k = 0$

Choose the $a_j$ with the largest absolute value.

$|a_j u_{jj}| > \sum_\limits{i\ne j} |a_i u_{ji}|$

$a_1 u_1 + a_2 u_2 + \cdots a_k u_k \ne 0$

Comment: Doesn't this assume that $|u_{ii}| > \sum_{j \neq i}|u_{ji}|$? Does this follow from the hypothesis? If we view the $u_j$'s as columns in an $n \times k$ matrix, and consider the matrix of absolute values, then the hypothesis is that the $j$th entry in the $j$th column is larger than the sum of the rest of the column, whereas your inequality seems to require it to be larger than the sum of the rest of the row. (Unless I'm misreading something.)

Comment: The sum is supposed to be over the i's.

Comment: @Bungo You are correct.... Suppose we found $k-n$ vectors to fill this out into a square matrix, then we took the transpose, and then used the method above....my alternative would be to say that any attempts at row reducing will leave k rows.

Answer (score 0):

make a set of $v_1 ...v_n \in R^k$ where $v_ij=u_ji$

if we can show $v_1 ...v_k$ are linearly independent, we can conclude that the rank is k and thus  $u_1 ...u_k$ are linearly independent.

For  $v_1 ...v_k$, we may be able to use Doug M's method of contradiction.